# How do I make a click detector that is in workspace enable a script in StarterGui? (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I am a scripting newbie, I just started so please answer very specifically. I have a model(named SpawnBox) with a click detector(named ClickDetector) inside of it. I also have a Gui(named Gui) in StarterGui. This gui has a frame(named Frame) inside of it which currently has a LocalScript(called LocalScript) inside. This LocalScript is disabled right now, so how would I enable the script with that click detector I talked about earlier? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a normal script as a child of the click detector, and inside it do the following:

-Reference the Click Detector as `script.Parent`
-Create a `.MouseClick` function which is where the code will be to enable the LocalScript

`.MouseClick` function makeup: `<Click Detector>.MouseClick:Connect(function(player) end)`

The `<Click Detector>.MouseClick` function carries a parameter which is the player (in `game.Players`) that clicked the button. Now you need to reference the player's `PlayerGui` since this is where each individual player's Gui's are held, and the only place where they and their properties can be changed. Since the parameter references the player in `game.Players`, you can just do `<player>.PlayerGui` to get the `PlayerGui`. (If you run the game and click the arrows in the explorer tab next to `Players`, a list of players, or just your own will pop up. Then click the arrow next to your player, and you will see `PlayerGui`. If you go further, you will see your ScreenGui named `Gui`, and if you click once more you will see your Frame named `Frame`). Inside of this frame is your LocalScript that we will enable.

`Disabled` is a boolean (`true` or `false`) value property of a script. In order to reference a property in Lua, we use a period `.`. Once we get the script, we can do `<LocalScript>.Disabled = false` to enable it. Here is what the structure of your code should look like:

`Define your Click Detector`
`Open a .MouseClick function with a parameter for the player who clicked`
`Get LocalScript by doing: local script = <player>.PlayerGui.Gui.Frame.LocalScript`
`Enable the script by doing: script.Disabled = false`
`end the .MouseClick function`

Links for extra help:
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ClickDetector
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/PlayerGui

Edited:
Here should be the hierarchy of the script in the Explorer:

ClickDetector
└ Script

Now your code would look something like this:

```lua
local ClickDetector = script.Parent --Reference your Click Detector for use in the script

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player) --'player' is the player who clicked it
     local enableScript = player.PlayerGui.Gui.Frame.LocalScript --Reference your script through the game explorer by using dots '.'
     enableScript.Disabled = false --Sets the 'Disabled' property to false (meaning it's now enabled)
end) --Close the .MouseClick function
```

I would recommend watching this video from AlvinBlox if you need help with object referencing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K7stCkqFBY

Comment: Thank you very much, but the script did not work for me. Can you please write out the script? You explained this very well.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope it helps now